# Joining several tables: table specified more than once error

Tags: postgresql, join

I am attempting to call data after joining all of my tables in a postgreSQL query. 
I am getting the following error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  table name "place" specified more than once
)
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

*After referring to similar posts and online resources*, I have attempted setting aliases (which only create new errors about not referring to the other tables in the FROM clause), reordering the table names (the cleanest, reordered chunk is posted below), and experimenting with UPDATE/FROM/JOIN as an alternative to SELECT/FROM/JOIN. However, I think I ultimately need to be using the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM place

INNER JOIN place ON place.key = form.key
INNER JOIN form ON form.id = items.formid
INNER JOIN items ON items.recid = rec.id
INNER JOIN rec ON rec.id = sub.recid
INNER JOIN sub ON sub.id = type.subid
INNER JOIN type ON type.name = det.typeid;
```

Comment: Your query has issues.  To what does the `det` alias correspond?  Also, you seem to have included the `place` table twice.

Comment: `det` is just the name of another table I'm joining to the rest. Your comment on including the `place` table twice is probably key-- I reference it to join it to the form table and then I use it in the FROM clause so that once all tables are joined, I can just pull all the data. I didn't consider this specifying `place` twice-- Does that need to be tweaked?

Comment: You're missing the point.  Your query references `det`, but that alias is not linked to an actual table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being the order of table names. The code below joined everything just fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM place

INNER JOIN form ON place.key = form.key
INNER JOIN items ON form.id = items.formid
INNER JOIN rec ON items.recid = rec.id
INNER JOIN sub ON rec.id = sub.recid
INNER JOIN type ON sub.id = type.subid
INNER JOIN det ON type.name = det.typeid;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have "place" in your query twice, which is allowed but you would have to alias the second use of the table "place". Also you reference something called "det", but it's not a table or alias anywhere in your query. If you want only one place that's fine, just remove the INNER JOIN place and move your place.key = form.key to the form join or to a where clause.

If you want to place tables in their because you are trying to join the table to itself the alias the second one, but you will want to make sure that you then have a clause to join those two tables on (could be part of an on or a where)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Often this type of issue can be solved by setting aliases as you recommended, but I was actually able to fix it by tweaking the order of table names. Also, 'det' is the actual name of a table in the database and I was able to call it in my query once I made the changes listed in my answer post.